# Accepting an answer that is clearly not the crowd favourite

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer, up-votes

I am the OP of the question [How do I deal with a coworker who unplugs my monitor because I didn't turn it off?](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/9255/how-do-i-deal-with-a-coworker-who-unplugs-my-monitor-because-i-didnt-turn-it-of) and I would like to accept the answer from AndreiRom (24 upvotes ATM), even if there is an answer that has already 70 upvotes.

Should I just accept the most upvoted answer or is it okay to accept my favourite answer? If the difference wasn't that big I wouldn't even think of asking here, but since the most upvoted answer has almost 3 times more upvotes, I wanted to ask about that matter here.

Comment: [Accepting an answer is not meant to be a definitive and final statement indicating that the question has now been answered perfectly. It simply means that the author received an answer that worked for him or her personally.](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer)

Comment: In your specific case I felt like the most upvoted answer didn't really provide an answer to what you were truly asking for anyway. You asked for ways to communicate and the most upvoted answer was just text telling you not to bother.  I think you should definitely  have the right to accept the answer that you did.

Answer (score 10):

It is up to you which answer you accept. The votes on the posts are the feedback of the community, but in the end, it is you who decides which one to accept.

If you hover over the check mark, when it is not highlighted, it says (with emphasis of mine),

> **Click to accept this answer because it solved your problem or was the most helpful in finding your solution** (click again to undo)

As it says, you can accept the answer which either solved your problem or was the most helpful in finding a solution.

From [this Meta SE answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/321725),

> - Don't hesitate to accept an answer that is well-written, suggests a good practice and works for you.
> - Otherwise, even if there are answers that are good enough but that you're not entirely satisfied by, you might wait 24 to 48 hours to give other people a chance to give you a better answer. A question with an accepted answer isn't as likely to receive further attention as one without an accepted answer.
> - Make sure that besides working for you, the answer is really good practice. Sometimes after the answer gets accepted, another comes in, uncovering the fact that previous one was in fact a bad hack.
> - **The bottom line is that you should accept the answer that you found to be the most helpful to you, personally.**

Comment: Absolutely right @AJ. You wrote the answer I would have written, so I upvote!